# How do I go about making a text box that allows for highlight-able and copyable text in the new UI?

Tags: unity, gui, text

I'm trying to make a simple chat system for our games lobby, however I am having issues making a text box that allows for text-highlighting. The Text component does not have interactible text, and the Inputfield allows for interaction, but I don't want the text to be editable in any way.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I would likely implement something where any attempts to change the text simply don't change the text. For example, there's an [`onValueChange`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChange.html) event for the [`InputField`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html). Attaching to this event and simply setting the text to its initial value will revert any changes made by the user.

This simple script achieves the desired effect:

```
public class InputFieldLockdown : MonoBehaviour {
    InputField textObject;
    string myText = "This is the text";

    void Start () {
        //Get the inputfield script and set its text value to the initial value
        textObject = this.GetComponentInChildren<InputField>();
        textObject.text = myText;
    }

    public void ValueChanged()
    {
        //When|if the value changes, reset it to its initial value
        textObject.text = myText;
    }
}
```

Attach this script to your InputField object. Next you'll need to associate the event in the Unity editor:

[image]

The only downside to this is pressing the backspace key, still causes the input caret to move backwards. This is a fairly minor downside though.

Comment: DeactivateInputField sadly does not allow for highlighting. I have been unable to figure out how to get onValueChange to return the actual value that was changed.. I can get it to call my methods, however I cannot get it to pass any data of what was changed.

Comment: I'll see if I can get a working example soon.

Comment: Sure thing, don't bust yourself over it though :)

Comment: All updated with working code.

Comment: Sweet, I used it and it works. Made some modifications and actually extended the InputField class. I'm a bit disappointed that Unity did not allow methods such as KeyPressed(Event evt) and properties like caretPosition to be overridden.